# Error 42601 al ejecutar un procedimiento almacenado en C# con PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, postgresql

Estoy intentando crear un método que ejecute un procedimiento almacenado que me permita insertar registros en una tabla. Sin embargo, me da error impidiendo que se ejecute el método.

Éste es el código:

```
    public bool Insertar(string nombre)
    {
        try
        {
            NpgsqlCommand comando = con.CreateCommand();
            comando.CommandText = "EXECUTE Insertar @telefono";
            comando.Parameters.Add("@telefono", parameterType: NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, size: 10, sourceColumn: "5").Value = nombre;
            con.Open();
            comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("se guardo");
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception er)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(er.Message,"Advertencia");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Y el error que recibo:

> 42601: Error de Sintaxis en cerca de << $1 >>

Comment: Que error te marca? Intenta completar la información para poder ayudarte. Error de compilación o Exception en el catch...

Comment: ya lo corregi había olvidado mostrar el mensaje

Comment: Por favor comparte el contenido del procedimiento `Insertar` también. Y el error está incompleto. Debes incluir el stack trace del error también.